# Please give some step by step idea on how to call a simple xquery in marklogic to remove the collection after QuerymarkLogic Processor in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

I am looking for some documentation or sample NIFI project for MarkLogic connector.

Here is the official ML NIFI [github repo](https://github.com/sshyran/MarkLogic-NiFi).
Here is the [getting start guide](https://marklogic.github.io/nifi/getting-started)

But I could not find any documentation nor sample template on how to use **Server Transform**
[image: QueryMarkLgoic Processor]

Questions:

1. Must I implement that server transform with [DataHub](https://github.com/marklogic/marklogic-data-hub)?
2. Must I implement it using REST API extension method? (There are other ways to do it like Data Service approach etc)
3. What is the difference in that **server transform** vs using CallRestExtentionMarkLoigc or ExecuteScriptMarkLogic nifi processors?
4. When should I use CallRestExtentionMarkLoigc  and when should I use ExecuteScriptMarkLogic? Any sample nifi templates I could download to refer to on how to use those two Processors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"REST server transform" refers to the transforms described in the docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms . I'll create a ticket in the Github project to consider how to better document that "REST server transform" is talking about these kinds of transforms.

And for your specific questions:

1. No, this is a generic REST transform.
2. It's not a "service extension", which is a custom endpoint instead of a transform.
3. CallRestExtension is for invoking a service extension as defined at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions . ExecuteScript is for sending a script of any code to MarkLogic.
4. CallRestExtension is for when you want to invoke a service extension that you've deployed to MarkLogic. ExecuteScript is handy for invoking arbitrary pieces of code without having to first deploy it to MarkLogic.

Comment: I am planning to use a "sync flag" collection on the document to implement a weekly changed sync between ML DB and a file folder. "Sync flag" will turn on whenever there is a change in the document. which way should I use to turn off that "Sync flag"? and Why?

I guess it could be done with "REST server transform" or service extension or ad-hoc script. 

I want to have some comparisons to clarify my understanding. Great thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you could use a REST transform to update the document when you query for it.