# Marklogic NIFI custom transform logic implmentation apprach comparison

Tags: apache-nifi, marklogic

It is related with this [MarkLogic NIFI question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862347/please-give-some-step-by-step-idea-on-how-to-call-a-simple-xquery-in-marklogic-t). I think it might be useful to spin off a new question.

I am planning to use a "sync flag" collection on the document to implement a weekly changed sync between ML DB and a file folder. "Sync flag" will turn on whenever there is a change in the document. which way should I use to turn off that "Sync flag" with NIFI flow? and Why?

I feel all below 3 methods could work.

1. Follow (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/transforms) to use **server trasform** setting in **QueryMarkLogic** processor.
2. Follow (https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/rest-dev/extensions) to implement a REST API Extension and use **CallRestExtnsion** processor.
3. Write a simple *xdmp:document-remove-collections* XQuery script with **ExecuteScript** processor.

For method 1 and 2, will those two ML Nifi processor auto place the **uri** in the context, as NIFI processor will process the document one by one. so I guess it will call the back end (preloaded XQuery) for each matched document one by one.

For method 3, how to pass in the URI? or maybe it is not possible in that approach.

I want to have some comparisons to clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#1 does not make sense to me. The transform in that context is about transforming content coming out of the query. There is also
ApplyTransformMarkLogic - but I am not sure if that is just transform of the document or if it can change collections.

#2 callRestExtension would be fine  - however, you need to set query parameters in the processor config for the URI and then consume it on the REST endpoint code.

#3 is simple.  Have the URI in as an attribute. Then in the script body, reference it:  `let $uri := '${uri}'` etc.  Then use `xdmp:document-remove-collections()`

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dateTime value on your documents - e.g. a last updated value - you can use the "State Index" and "State Index Type" properties on `QueryMarkLogic` to constrain your query each time on the property/element/path defined by "State Index" and the highest value of that property/element/path the last time `QueryMarkLogic` ran. That avoids the need for updating all of the documents that QueryMarkLogic just matched on, but it does require have a useful dateTime on your documents along with an index on it.